# ngModel does not give the right value on ngFor loops

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I do `ngFor` for `[(ngModel)]` the result was wrong. I try to follow based on this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ashLynsRblWWl7Adb4Wg?p=preview).

```
<div class="answer-field" *ngFor="let answer of data.answer.scheme_group_id; let i=index; trackBy:trackByIndex;">
    <div class="answer-numbering">
        {{answer}}
    </div>
    <input class="answer-input" [(ngModel)]="data.answer.scheme_group_id[i]" name="answer_fields" (input)="onAnswerChange(answer.answer_id,$event.target.value)" type="text" placeholder="Type your answer here" />
</div>
```

But, when I hardcoded the value of `[(ngModel)]=A` and `[(ngModel)]=B` then I got no problems on getting the value of `A` and `B`. The codes as below:

```
<div class="answer-field">
    <div class="answer-numbering">
        A
    </div>
    <input class="answer-input" [(ngModel)]="A" name="answer_fields" (input)="onAnswerChange(answer.answer_id,$event.target.value)" type="text" placeholder="Type your answer here" />
</div>  
<div class="answer-field">
    <div class="answer-numbering">
        B
    </div>
    <input class="answer-input" [(ngModel)]="B" name="answer_fields" (input)="onAnswerChange(answer.answer_id,$event.target.value)" type="text" placeholder="Type your answer here" />
</div>
```

---

The codes for debug:

```
A:any; 
  B:any;
  answer_field:any;
  onAnswerChange(answerValue : string ) {  
      let answer_field_change = true;
      this.event.publish("answer_field_changes",answer_field_change);

      let output_data = {"A":this.A, "B":this.B};
      console.log('output_data');
      console.log(output_data);

  }


 trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
```

---

Guys..please help me.. My expected output is to use `[(ngModel)]` in `ngFor` loop but still does not work at all.

---

My sample data for `data.answer.scheme_group_id`:

[image]

Comment: I've updated the sample image data @Melchia

Comment: Your `data.answer.scheme_group_id` is an array of object so your `ngModel` will take an object as value so it can not bind. `ngModel` just can bind a simple type value like string or number

Comment: So how I can change it to value instead of object?I need to get the value from that object.

Comment: Oh. Just wait. Maybe i am wrong. Try `[(ngModel)] = "answer"`

Comment: There will be several `input`s not only one...

Comment: Please re-procduce your project in https://stackblitz.com so we can play with it

Comment: You are using `A` and `B` variables in component, but nowhere are they in your (not hardcoded) template code, so what do you expect that the values should be for those variables?